# How to remove iptables rule

Tags: iptables

I have this rule in my iptables:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -nvL --line-numbers

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 14 packets, 1950 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 14 packets, 1950 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 577 packets, 41182 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 8090
```

I tried to delete it using:

```
sudo iptables -D OUTPUT 1
```

by I got this error:

```
iptables: Index of deletion too big.
```

So after some searching on the web, I found out that should be able to delete all the rules for the chain like this:

```
sudo iptables -F OUTPUT
```

The output of this command is nothing, but when I rerun the`sudo iptables -t nat -nvL --line-numbers` command to list the existing rules afterwards, nothing got deleted. What am I missing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your rule was defined in table nat, so you must add **-t nat** explicitly.

```
sudo iptables -D OUTPUT 1 -t nat
```

If you haven't specific the table name, the default action will use '-t filter' implicitly.